# IOError: Errno 110 Connection timed out

Tags: raspberry-pi, timeout, i2c, ioerror, smbus

I've try to connect a [Heart Rate Sensor](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Finger-clip-Heart-Rate-Sensor-with-shell-p-2420.html#) with raspberry pi Zero. to do it, I use the I2C port communication. 
I have a sensor in 0x50 adress and work correctly, but when I did a loop for a long time, the error appear (110).

For example, I put a while to see continuosly the data and the error appeared (after half minut), and now the sensor doesn't connected to the I2C bus. (with the comand i2cdetect -y 1 I don't see any sensor connected, where before, It was.
I've had to disconnect and connect to use it again, and when I do a number of reads, come back again the error,

You know why? Can you help me?

```
import smbus
    while True:
    bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
    b = bus.read_byte_data(0x50,0)
    print b
```

Comment: Do you have /boot/config.txt (PiZero) or whatever it is for your Pi with correct I2C settings such as baudrate?